# SVN Merging different projects into one master project

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

Our development team of 24 uses Tortoise svn for windows and command line for Ubuntu. We started off with one **master** folder in SVN . But we faced some conflicts and issues in QA releases and decided to have three more copies of the master namely Alpha , Beta and Gamma. Team Alpha will always commit to Alpha folder. Team Beta will always commit to beta folder and so on.
Folder structure:

**Before**

- Master

**After**

- Master
- Alpha
- Beta
- Gamma

The problem we have now is while merging files because 3 teams work in different modules and sometimes in common files. When we try to merge files from Alpha , Beta's newly added files go missing from the Master.
What approach should we follow to merge changes from **Alpha , Beta and Gamma** into **Master** before **releasing the Master to QA** ?

Comment: Having different branches for different teams is quite strange. Can you explain what kind of conflicts you had before with QA releases, and how different branches helped with that. Because understanding the actual problem would make it easier to give you good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Master" folder should be considered as the "trunk" from SVN Red Book Classical Layout (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.branchmerge.maint.html). "Alpha", "Beta" and "Gamma" are "branches", according to the same reference.

Every "milestone" from "Alpha", "Beta" or "Gamma" should be reintegrated into the "Master" (see steps here: http://technology.amis.nl/2010/02/25/subversion-branching-merging-and-reintegration). Thereafer, the other teams will have to merge in their copies a range of revisions (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html, see Cherrypicking).

In TortoiseSVN, these operations are in <kbd>Merge</kbd> command (TortoiseSVN > Merge into the target directory).

Comment: Tried reintegration method from beta into master: but what it does is updates files which are not supposed to be updated in master (coz some files in master are more updated than beta ). Any solution for this ?

Comment: If "Master" files are more updated than "Beta", so I think you jumped some part at the process, but to resolve you just need to merge the "Master" files into "Beta" first, and then, when "Beta" comes stable, reintegrate all the changes into "Master" again.